# Counting comparisons and swaps in a quick sort

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort

I'm running a quick sort on 2000 integers read from a file and count the comparisons and swaps but I'm not sure if my counters are in the right place as my numbers seem off, or is something wrong with the sort?

```
public int partition(int array[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        int pivot = array[low];

        while(low < high)
        {
            while(pivot < array[high] && low < high)
            {
                high = high - 1;
                compCounter++;
            }
            if(high != low)
            {
                array[low] = array[high];
                SwapCounter++;
                low++;
            }
            while(array[low] < pivot && low < high)
            {
                low = low +1;
                compCounter++;
            }
            if(high != low)
            {
                array[high] = array[low];
                SwapCounter++;
                high--;
            }
        }

        SwapCounter++;
        int temp = array[high];
        array[high] = pivot;
        return high;


    } 

    public void quickSort(int array[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        if (low < high) 
        { 
            int pivotPoint = partition(array, low, high); 
            quickSort(array, low, pivotPoint-1); 
            quickSort(array, pivotPoint+1, high); 
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I check your code but I think you do some more works (and maybe produce invalid result in some special case). I change your code in some how which is true and you can find it with some search and place counter in correct place.

```
    private static int CompCounter, SwapCounter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a = {3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7 , 4, -1};
        quickSort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }

    public static int partition(int array[], int low, int high) {
        int pivot = array[high];

        int lowBound = low;
        for (int i = low; i < high; i++)
        {
            CompCounter++;
            if (array[i] < pivot) {
                int temp = array[lowBound];
                array[lowBound] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
                lowBound++;
                SwapCounter++;
            }
        }

        SwapCounter++;
        array[high] = array[lowBound];
        array[lowBound] = pivot;
        return lowBound;
    }

    public static void quickSort(int array[], int low, int high) {
        if (low < high)
        {
            int pivotPoint = partition(array, low, high);
            quickSort(array, low, pivotPoint - 1);
            quickSort(array, pivotPoint + 1, high);
        }
    }
```

If you want, you can use another way to partition for sort (another algorithm):

```
    public static int partitionSecondWay(int array[], int low, int high) {
    int pivot = array[low];
    int i = low - 1;
    int j = high + 1;
    while (true)
    {
        do
        {
            i++;
            CompCounter++;
        } while (array[i] < pivot);
        do
        {
            j--;
            CompCounter++;
        } while (array[j] > pivot);
        if (i >= j)
        {
            CompCounter++;
            return j; // notice if you use this way, then in quicksort you
            // must use quicksort(array, low, partition) and 
            // quicksort(array, partition + 1, high)
        }

        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        SwapCounter++;
    }
}
```

I hope these helps you. If something is wrong, comment it.